# Referencing a column alias in the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, column-alias

Is there any way to return an "AS" result using WHERE or otherwise?

I'm doing a SUBSTRING on the FONE1 column and trying to return the DDD = 31 but I get the error,
Code: 1054. Unknown column 'DDD' in 'where clause'  0.000 sec

-->

```
SELECT  **SUBSTRING(FONE1,1,2) AS DDD**, FONE1, F1STA,LASTCALL
FROM discador_processados
WHERE fila_mailing = 2638
AND F1STA ='ANSWER'
AND CLASSE1 IN ('VC2','VC3')
**AND DDD = 31**
AND LASTCALL BETWEEN '2020-10-02 00:00:00' AND '2020-10-30 23:59:59'
```

The idea would be to get the return below

```
DDD    FONE1     F1STA      LASTCALL 
31  31999999999 ANSWER  2020-10-02 09:08:13
31  31999999999 ANSWER  2020-10-02 09:09:16
31  31999999999 ANSWER  2020-10-02 09:17:41
```

Thanks!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  But you cannot re-use an alias in the `WHERE` clause.  You need to repeat the expression, use a subquery, use a CTE, or use a lateral join to define the value.

Comment: Use a derived table.

Comment: I've tagged your request `mysql`, because "Code: 1054. Unknown column" sounds like MySQL. Please correct this, if it's wrong. What data type is `FONE1`?

Comment: use ` and SUBSTRING(FONE1,1,2)=31` as I know you cannot use an alias in 'where' closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend writing the `WHERE` as:

```
WHERE fila_mailing = 2638 AND
      F1STA ='ANSWER' AND
      CLASSE1 IN ('VC2', 'VC3') AND
      FONE1 LIKE '31%' AND
      LASTCALL >= '2020-10-02' AND
      LASTCALL < '2020-10-31'
```

Note the changes to the logic:

- `FONE1` appears to be a string, so the comparison uses **string** operations.
- The `DATETIME` comparisons uses `>=` and `<` rather than `BETWEEN` so the last second on the last day is not missed.
- The date format is simplified.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use output column alias in `WHERE` clause, because the output column expressionis not evaluated yet and hense simply not exists.

But you may do this in `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(FONE1,1,2) AS DDD, FONE1, F1STA,LASTCALL
FROM discador_processados
WHERE fila_mailing = 2638
  AND F1STA ='ANSWER'
  AND CLASSE1 IN ('VC2','VC3')
  AND LASTCALL BETWEEN '2020-10-02 00:00:00' AND '2020-10-30 23:59:59'
HAVING DDD = 31
```

And pay attention to [Gordon Linoff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1144035/gordon-linoff)'s answer - it is very useful.